# How do i fix the warning

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I have two classes in my project: `SIAViewController.h`, and its sub-class `cell.h`.

In `cell.h` I have

```
@interface cell : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic)CGRect frame;
@property(assign,nonatomic)UIImage *image;
@property(nonatomic)int tag;
@property(nonatomic)bool userInteractionEnabled;
@property(retain,nonatomic)UITapGestureRecognizer *addGestureRecognizer;
@end
```

And in `SIAViewController.m`:

```
int x=20,y=50,t=1;
cell *tank[9][9];
for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=8;j++)
    {
        tank[i][j]=[[cell alloc]init];
        tank[i][j].frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 35, 35);
        UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"s.jpg"];
        [tank[i][j] setImage:myImage];
        tank[i][j].tag=t;
        tank[i][j].userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
        tank[i][j]. addGestureRecognizer=recognizer;
        [self.view addSubview:tank[i][j]];
        x+=35;
        t++;
    }
    y+=35;
    x=20;
}
```

And while running the project I'm receiving the thread incompatible pointer types sending cell __strong to parameter of type uiview. Can anyone help me. I'm new to xcode. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that UIView is a superclass of your table view cell. It means that if some property is expected to be an UITableViewCell, but you pass in a generic UIView instance, that UIView may be, but not necessarily, also an UITableViewCell. That's why the compiler warns you. If you know that your instance to be set is really an UITableViewCell disguised to an UIView, you can safely ignore this warning, as Objective-C is a dynamic language; the type declarations are only for fooling the compiler; type matching occurs during runtime.

Comment: See i receive the thread Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[cell superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68441d0'